# Realm Android creates an object with null values

Tags: android, realm

I'm experiencing some peculiar behavior with Realm for Android. When I commit my User object to Realm, it seems to create another User with all null values. Has anyone run into this before, and am I doing something wrong?

```
User user = ...fetched from remote 
Realm realm = null;
try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            // Here I get no results as expected, I have yet to commit the user to the realm. 
            for(User queriedUser: realm.where(User.class).findAll()) {
                Log.v("qwer", "Before: " + queriedUser);
            }

            // Commit the user to the realm
            realm.insertOrUpdate(user);

            // Results in 2 records: the User I just committed, and another User with all null values.
            for(User queriedUser: realm.where(User.class).findAll()) {
                Log.v("qwer", "After: " + queriedUser);
            }
        }
    });
} finally {
    if(realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you verify that `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` does not have this odd behavior?